# ORA-00920: Operador Relacional no Válido

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo problema con la siguiente sentencia:

```
SELECT primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, primer_nombre, segundo_nombre FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE departamento=(SELECT cod_departamento_ips FROM DEPARTAMENTOS_IPS WHERE nombre LIKE 'Administracion' OR 'IT');
```

Lo único que necesito es que me arroje una tabla con 2 datos, uno de un usuario cuyo departamento es 'Administración' y otro de un usuario cuyo departamento 'IT'.
Lo he intentado de muchas maneras pero siempre me genera los errores:

> ORA-00920: Operador Relacional no Válido

> ORA-01427: La Subconsulta de Una Sola Fila Devuelve Más de Una Fila

Agradezco cualquier ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error que tienes, indica que la subconsulta devuelve los dos valores, hay multiples maneras de resolver esto, una de ellas es a traves del UNION, a traves de esto puedes unir dos o mas SELECT mientras tengan la misma estructura, una solucion seria la siguiente

```
SELECT primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, primer_nombre, segundo_nombre FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE departamento=(SELECT cod_departamento_ips FROM DEPARTAMENTOS_IPS WHERE nombre LIKE 'Administracion')
UNION 
SELECT primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, primer_nombre, segundo_nombre FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE departamento=(SELECT cod_departamento_ips FROM DEPARTAMENTOS_IPS WHERE nombre LIKE 'IT');
```

Inicialmente lo que sucede con esto, es que dicha subconsulta te devuelve mas de un valor, en este caso, otra cosa que te recomendaria investigar es el uso del IN, ya que esto devuelve una lista a traves de la cual el si podria comparar, no estoy seguro pero seria algo como esto

```
SELECT primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, primer_nombre, segundo_nombre FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE departamento IN (SELECT cod_departamento_ips FROM DEPARTAMENTOS_IPS WHERE nombre LIKE 'Administracion' OR 'IT');
```

No estoy 100% seguro de que esa sea la sintaxis correcta, pero es algo con el estilo, sin embargo con el UNION deberia funcionarte

Espero te sirva, quedo atento

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ya logre solucionarlo. Use el IN en vez del = al inicio de la subconsulta y me genero los dos datos que necesitaba. La sentencia final quedo de esta manera: `SELECT primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, primer_nombre, segundo_nombre FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE departamento IN (SELECT cod_departamento_ips FROM DEPARTAMENTOS_IPS WHERE nombre LIKE 'Administracion' OR nombre LIKE 'IT');`

Comment: Perfecto, como en el segundo query que coloque, exito!

Comment: @Daniel, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) esta respuesta si te ha sido útil.